# How do i get started in Network Programming?

Tags: c++, c, vb.net, network-programming, operating-system

I would like to get started in Network Programming on anything like Web, Window App, Apple device, Android device but i don know where to start all these thing...and i also have a good solid foundation of C/C++, Java, VB.net.

I have no clue about what hardware and other resources that I will need...If you work or are knowledgeable in this area, how did you get started and what are some good resource for a beginner?

I'm very addict to searching new technology and new programming language, please suggest as much as you can possibly give thx you.

Comment: Post this in Meta,maybe this question would fit there.It clearly doesn't in StackOverflow.

Comment: this question Bong is not appropriate for the forum. You may want to try a more general programmer's exchange. This is for more "specific" programming questions.

Comment: My suggestion: install Linux and read http://advancedlinuxprogramming;com/ and some other books

Comment: @Rüppell'sVulture: not at all. Meta is for stuff about _Stack Overlow_ itself & the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: Sorry for posting this kind of question because i don know about this stuff really. anyway thank for people who pointing out the source it very good help even it just on UNIX. Even though i don get much help it ok, even it not a appropriate question maybe but it need some helpful answer to point out the newbie of this field to the right place.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest this book by Richard Stevens http://www.unpbook.com/

Comment: Thx for the post i hope you can point out other source that relate to Network programming.